# Getting the value of a label in JSP or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a label called Promotion and Wholesale in my jsp page which will have the values of Yes or No. I want to extract the labels value(Yes or No) and validate it but I am not sure how. Request help. The sample code of the label is as below and image is as below.

```
<li class="FormFieldTitleTwo" style="padding-left: 10px;"><spring:message    
 code="label.promotion" />:</li>
 <li class="Checkbox">  
 <div class="FormFieldLabel"><spring:message code="yesNo.true"></spring:message></div>
  </li>
```

[image: The Label Image]

Comment: we have two views management and employee. This label is in the employee view. At the management view it is a checkbox. I am working on the employee view where it will always be a label.

Comment: that means value is hidden . save it in a hidden field and post it !! how you show that value now ?

Answer (score 0):

Add two input text fields with hidden type. Set its value by how you set your label. And then take those values in javascript.

```
<inputy type="hidden" name="promotion" id="promotion" value="(your code to set value)" />

<inputy type="hidden" name="wholesale" id="wholesale" value="(your code to set value)" />
```